# Matrix multiplication for numpy array of different dimensions

Tags: python, numpy

Assume  we have 6 vectors (each vector has 1*4 dimension) in a numpy array having shape (3, 2, 4) like this:

```
A=np.array([   [[1,2,3,4], [5,6,7,8]],    [[ 7,8 ,9,10],[ 11,12 ,13,14]],    [[ 15,16 ,17,18],[ 19,20 ,21,22]]   ])
```

Assume we have single Matrix B having dimensions 4*4 in a np.array form having (4, 4) shape as follows

```
B=np.array([  [1,2,3,4],     [5,6,7,8],      [9,10,11,12], [13,14,15,16]])
```

How to perform matrix multiplication of matrix B to every vector of the 6 vectors in A and the result have the same shape as A
the resalut like this

```
result=np.array([   [[1,2,3,4]@B, [5,6,7,8]@B],    [[ 7,8 ,9,10]@B,[ 11,12 ,13,14]@B],    [[ 15,16 ,17,18]@B,[ 19,20 ,21,22]@B]   ])

result=np.array([[[ 90, 100, 110, 120],
        [202, 228, 254, 280]],

       [[258, 292, 326, 360],
        [370, 420, 470, 520]],

       [[482, 548, 614, 680],
        [594, 676, 758, 840]]])
```

Comment: Please share how you would do this using loops (it helps to see the looping version when writing the vectorized version). This will also show the expected output so we have something to compare to.

Comment: The right part of `@` has not the same shape of `Stu_data`

Comment: Thank you for response, so should I add an extra dimension?

Comment: Yes or no, I don't know, it depends on what you want exactly :-). Provide a small example of the expected output. I'm pretty sure you don't need loop.

Comment: I suppose you don't want the result of `A @ B` but the same shape, right ?

Comment: yes, I want the result in the same shape, with each vector is matrix multiplied by B

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit:

It seems you are looking for [`np.matmul`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.matmul.html):

```
>>> np.matmul(A, B)
array([[[ 90, 100, 110, 120],
        [202, 228, 254, 280]],

       [[258, 292, 326, 360],
        [370, 420, 470, 520]],

       [[482, 548, 614, 680],
        [594, 676, 758, 840]]])
```

---

However, you can probably use [numpy broadcasting](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html) to get what you expect:

```
>>> Stu_data[:, :, None] * A_data

array([[[[   1,    4,    9,   16],
         [   5,   12,   21,   32],
         [   9,   20,   33,   48],
         [  13,   28,   45,   64]],

        [[  55,  132,  231,  352],
         [ 275,  396,  539,  704],
         [ 495,  660,  847, 1056],
         [ 715,  924, 1155, 1408]]],


       [[[   1,    4,    9,   16],
         [   5,   12,   21,   32],
         [   9,   20,   33,   48],
         [  13,   28,   45,   64]],

        [[   1,    4,    9,   16],
         [   5,   12,   21,   32],
         [   9,   20,   33,   48],
         [  13,   28,   45,   64]]],


       [[[   1,    4,    9,   16],
         [   5,   12,   21,   32],
         [   9,   20,   33,   48],
         [  13,   28,   45,   64]],

        [[   1,    4,    9,   16],
         [   5,   12,   21,   32],
         [   9,   20,   33,   48],
         [  13,   28,   45,   64]]]])
```

Shapes:

```
>>> A_data
(4, 4)

>>> Stu_data
(3, 2, 4)

>>> Stu_data[:, :, None].shape
(3, 2, 1, 4)

>>> (Stu_data[:, :, None] * A_data).shape
(3, 2, 4, 4)
```

Comment: When I edited the question I accidentally removed the reference to using the `@` operator, which would imply matrix multiplication, not element-wise. That's my fault.

Comment: @jared. Oh I see. but `Stu_data @ A_data` works as expected, no?

Comment: Or maybe `np.einsum('ijk, zk',Stu_data, A_data)`. What the OP wants is really not clear :-)

Comment: Exactly, they both work and it's not clear what the expected result should be. For now I'll be voting to close as needing more details/clarity.